# Elastic search showing same 10 results for any queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am playing with Elastic search. I am trying to search using js client like this.

```
const request = Client(
  'helpdoc',
 'https://4c834.com:443',
  'a0FpXzhZb0JURXBfejFzeGdFake',
  {}
)
```

```
const {hits} = await request()
    .query('dfsjhfsjdhfsjdfhsjfhsdjfsfsdf')
    .search()
console.log(hits)
```

No matter what I put in `query()`, I always get the same 10 results.

What I am doing wrong? Help please

Comment: which version of esclient is this?

Comment: feels like the syntax is off for constructor. Also, the query is not correct, you are not specifying the field at all. Can you link to the docs you are referring

Comment: @TusharShahi here is the doc I am following : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/8.10/search-applications-search.html